Generar múltiples PDF con MPDF
estoy desarrollando un sitio para venta de entradas a eventos,estos eventos tienen diferentes tipos de entrada,ahora,a la hora de realizar la compra se le debe enviar al usuario un correo con tantos pdf como tipos de entrada adquiridas,por lo que necesito generar varios pdf con un ciclo for,la idea es crear tantos pdf como registros,los cuales son tipos de entradas adquiridas para un evento,pero solo me está generando uno,el código que tengo es el siguiente:
    <?php 
include("conexion.php");
include("mpdf/autoload.php");
require("FlowApi.class.php");
include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
/*ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);*/
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


require 'vendormailer/autoload.php';

$codigo_orden = "1211";
$sth = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM compras WHERE codigo_orden = ?");
$sth->bindParam(1, $codigo_orden);
$sth->execute();

if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) {

foreach ($sth as $row ) 
{ 

   $id_solicitante = $row["id_solicitante"];
   $solicitante = $row["solicitante"];
   $correo = $row["correo"];
   $id_artista = $row["id_artista"];
   $artista = $row["artista"];
   $productora_id = $row["productora_id"];
   $productora = $row["productora"];
   $id_evento = $row["id_evento"];
   $evento = $row["evento"];
   $local = $row["local"];
   $tipo_entrada = $row["tipo_entrada"];
   $cantidad = $row["cantidad"];
   $fecha = $row["fecha"];
   $fecha_evento = $row["fecha_evento"];
   $mensaje = $row["mensaje"];
   $monto = $row["monto"];
   
}

}

$tipo_entrada = explode(",", $tipo_entrada);


$artista = "Cheryl";
$solicitante = "Horacio Quesada";
$carpeta = "uploads/qr/";
if (!file_exists($carpeta)) 
     {
    mkdir($carpeta,0777);
     }
$id_artista = "272";


for ($i=0; $i < count($tipo_entrada); $i++) 
{ 

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'A4-L']);
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/bootstrap.css');
$stylesheet2 = file_get_contents('css/nueva.css');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet2,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->keepColumns = true;
$contenido = $tipo_entrada[$i]; 
$ecc = "H";
$tamano = "5";
$codeFile = $codigo = rand(1000,1000000).'.png';

   QRcode::png($contenido, $carpeta.$codeFile, $ecc, $tamano);
$html = 
'<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-borderless imagen-fondo">


<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><img class="imagen" src="img/logo/Logo_encabezado.png"></td>
  <td class="centrado"><br><br><br><p class="segundo">ECOVENPAY</p><br>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</div>
</table>
</div>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

/*  $mpdf->WriteHTML('<div class="table-responsive">');

  $mpdf->WriteHTML('<table class="table table-borderless imagen-fondo">


<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><img class="imagen" src="img/logo/Logo_encabezado.png"></td>
  <td class="centrado"><br><br><br><p class="segundo">ECOVENPAY</p><br>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</div>
</table>
</div>');*/
  
  $mpdf->WriteHTML('<div class="table-responsive">');

  $mpdf->WriteHTML('<table class="table table-borderless imagen-fondo">


<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><img class="" src="'.$carpeta.$codeFile.'"></td>
  <td class="centrado"><br><br><br><h4>Artista: '.$artista.'</h4>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>

</table>
</div>');

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="33%">{DATE j-m-Y}</td>
        <td width="33%" align="center">{PAGENO}/{nbpg}</td>
        <td width="33%" style="text-align: right;">ECOVENPAY</td>
    </tr>
</table>');
 
// ÚLTIMA SECCIÓN
$solicitante = utf8_decode($solicitante);
$mpdf->Output('uploads/compras/'.$solicitante.'.pdf',\Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);
#$mpdf->Output('uploads/compras/'.$solicitante.'.pdf','F');

}
?>

Cualquier ayuda la agradeceré montones. Muchas gracias.

Nunca cambias el nombre del archivo. Si tu código genera y guarda 8 archivos, todos con el mismo nombre, al final, vas a tener solo el último. Si quieres tener 8, ve cambiando el nombre de cada uno. Tan simple como ir añadiendo el número de archivo, por ejemplo, con un -1, -2, etc.

Hola @jachguate,muchas gracias,funciona perfectamente,bendiciones

Saludos de nuevo,tengo otro problema,ahora necesito generar tantos pdf como la cantidad adquirida de cada tipo de entrada,por ejemplo si se compraron 3 entradas de sol este y 2 de gradería sur,se deben generar 3 pdf con la información de sol este y dos pdf con la información de gradería sur.Gracias.

yo pondría como nombre $solicitante + $localidad + $numeroDeArchivo
